# Universal HTML link to Desktop

Tags: html, hyperlink, desktop

We offer a course to students were they must download folders and files to their desktop to access them and work on some webpages. We also have some links in the online course which will relate to the student files.

As the path to the desktop changes for each user I was wondering if there is any way to create a universal path that would link to all users desktops.

So a standard link to a file on the desktop may look like this with the username of the Windows User account being MyUser:

"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CourseFiles\index.htm"

Is there a way of changing MyUser for something that will work for all User Accounts?

Mick

Comment: Why not put them in a ZIP file and relatively reference the folders?

Comment: You should probably use a relative path for all of that, and avoid using an explicit path for one that you can't be sure of.

Comment: [{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}](http://superuser.com/a/398966/258902)

Comment: Alternatively, you could create an SMB share and link to that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for that with HTML. Just use relative paths when linking to other files.

Comment: Relative links wouldn't work. They will be extracting a zip file to the desktop and then parts of online course they are viewing will be referencing files that have been extracted to the links would be in a website and would be linking to files on the desktop